# Issue on Displaying Bootstrap Popover On Small Screens

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Can you please take a look at [this demo](http://www.bootply.com/Yi9cmDgBu7) and let me know why I am not able to position the popover on the bottom or top of the hyperlink?

as you can see I already added

```
placement : 'auto right'
```

but this is not working too!

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As stated in their **<kbd>[`docs`](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#popovers-options)</kbd>** for `placement` option:

> **`Type:`** *String|function*
>
> **`Default:`** *right*
>
> **`Description:`** *How to position the popover - top | bottom | left | right | auto. When "auto" is specified, it will dynamically reorient the popover. For
>   example, if placement is "auto left", the popover will display to the
>   left when possible, otherwise it will display right.*

when you specify `auto left` as `placement` option, it will display to the left whenever possible else it will display to the right i.e. ***they are targeting on opposite direction***.

So if you want to make it appear on `top` you need to specify either `top` or `bottom` in `placement` option along with `auto`.

**Ex**

```
placement:'auto top'
```

Alternatively, you can specify it in `html5` `data-placement` attribute for `element`

**Ex**

```
<a href="#" class="" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="top" title="Move to Down On small" data-content="" role="button">Smart PopOver</a>
```

**[DEMO](http://www.bootply.com/Yi9cmDgBu7)**